# Is there a doc on how to setup the dev env for Polymer

Tags: polymer

It seems that you have to manually checkout a bunch of repos, and when I tried to run the core-tests runner.html, they reference htmls from outside the folder which is restricted by the browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polymer uses a notion of components. We define a `component` as a set of shareable resources in a folder. All of your components should be together in one master folder (I usually call it `components`). This way one component can reference another component by looking in `../<component-name>/`.

A project will generally look something like this:

```
my-project/
   index.html
   components/  <-- could be symlink or a server redirection
     platform/  <-- polyfills
     polymer/   <-- polymer
     core-ajax/ <-- a custom element
     ...
```

`core-tests` in particular, is itself a component. It lives in the `components` folder and runs tests on other components (by looking at `../<component-name>/` as above).

So, if your web-root in the example above is `my-project`, you should be able to access `my-project/components/core-tests/runner.html` to run those component tests.

There are multiple ways to populate the `components` folder. The easiest way is to use Bower (http://bower.io) with a command like `bower install Polymer/core-elements`.

You can also use Git checkouts, or ZIP archives. There is a nifty utility for downloading Bower packages as zip files at `bowerarchiver.appspot.com`. E.g.:

http://bowerarchiver.appspot.com/archive?core-elements=Polymer/core-elements

Will get you a zip of the `core-elements` Polymer component, with all of it's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Yeoman generators that can help you with starting off: yo polymer and yo element

yo polymer is based on the [polymer seed-element](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/seed-element) and yo element is based on the [polymer-boilerplate](https://github.com/webcomponents/polymer-boilerplate).

I ended up writing [a blog post on getting the hang of these different setups](http://blog.stefanritter.com/post/91627263720/starting-a-polymer-project). If you get the latest version of the generator from the github repo it will scaffold an app for you:

```
npm install -g git+https://github.com/yeoman/generator-polymer.git
```

Also make sure to have a look at the [vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) task to concat your components.